# Websphere Commerce Developer 7 - FEP 7 Enabled in DB but not in EAR

Tags: websphere-7, ibm-rad, ibm-was, websphere-commerce, wcs

I've been recently involved in a project which use WebSphere Commerce to build an enterprise ecommerce. I've been struggling with the environent setup since monday, without getting a anything fully functional.

My goal is to install:

- RAD 8.0.4.3
- WAS 7.0.0.35
- WebSphere Commerce Developer 7.0.0.8 (Fix Pack 8)
- **Feature Pack 7 (7.0.7.0)**
- Oracle 11g enterprise instance connected to WCS

I guess the stack is quite old, but I managed to install pretty much everything, including Oracle and the DB setup within WCS. I'm stuck at FEP enablement, which I'm trying to perform using **enableFeature.bat**. The feature get installed and "activated in the DB", but not in the EAR.

Have you got any suggestion on how to force the feature enablament within the ear?

Plese find attached the log coming from checkEnablementStatus.bat.

```html
File di build: C:\IBM\WCDE_E~1\components\common\xml\enableFeatureForToolkit.xml

ANTContribUtilities:

checkFeatureName:

init:
[getProfileName] profile: WCDE_E~1_155450

prepareJaclClasspath:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\IBM\WCDE_E~1\config\deployment\properties
  [replace] Replaced 3 occurrences in 1 files.
  [replace] Replaced 6 occurrences in 1 files.

CheckEnablementStatus:
     [echo] component list file = C:\IBM\WCDE_E~1\properties\version\FEP7.componentlist
[forEachTask] featureName: foundation

CheckPrereqInDB:
[CheckFeaturePrerequisite] La funzione foundation è abilitata in DB.

CheckFeature:
     [echo] ------------------------------------------------------
     [echo] Feature           - INSTALLED -        - DB -        - EAR - 
     [echo] ------------------------------------------------------
     [echo] foundation        7.0.7.0        7.0.7.0        N/A
     [echo] ------------------------------------------------------
[forEachTask] featureName: management-center

CheckPrereqInDB:
[CheckFeaturePrerequisite] La funzione management-center è abilitata in DB.

CheckFeature:
     [echo] ------------------------------------------------------
     [echo] Feature           - INSTALLED -        - DB -        - EAR - 
     [echo] ------------------------------------------------------
     [echo] management-center        7.0.7.0        7.0.7.0        7.0.0.0
     [echo] ------------------------------------------------------
[forEachTask] featureName: store-enhancements

CheckPrereqInDB:
[CheckFeaturePrerequisite] La funzione store-enhancements è abilitata in DB.

CheckFeature:
     [echo] ------------------------------------------------------
     [echo] Feature           - INSTALLED -        - DB -        - EAR - 
     [echo] ------------------------------------------------------
     [echo] store-enhancements        7.0.7.0        7.0.7.0        N/A
     [echo] ------------------------------------------------------
[forEachTask] featureName: content-version

CheckPrereqInDB:
[CheckFeaturePrerequisite] La funzione content-version è abilitata in DB.

CheckFeature:
     [echo] ------------------------------------------------------
     [echo] Feature           - INSTALLED -        - DB -        - EAR - 
     [echo] ------------------------------------------------------
     [echo] content-version        7.0.7.0        7.0.7.0        N/A
     [echo] ------------------------------------------------------
[forEachTask] featureName: social-commerce

CheckPrereqInDB:
[CheckFeaturePrerequisite] La funzione social-commerce è abilitata in DB.

CheckFeature:
     [echo] ------------------------------------------------------
     [echo] Feature           - INSTALLED -        - DB -        - EAR - 
     [echo] ------------------------------------------------------
     [echo] social-commerce        7.0.7.0        7.0.7.0        N/A
     [echo] ------------------------------------------------------
[forEachTask] featureName: location-services

CheckPrereqInDB:
[CheckFeaturePrerequisite] La funzione location-services è abilitata in DB.

CheckFeature:
     [echo] ------------------------------------------------------
     [echo] Feature           - INSTALLED -        - DB -        - EAR - 
     [echo] ------------------------------------------------------
     [echo] location-services        7.0.7.0        7.0.7.0        N/A
     [echo] ------------------------------------------------------
GENERAZIONE COMPLETATA

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 5 seconds
HeadlessWorkspaceSettings: INITIAL autoBuild=false maxFile=-1
HeadlessWorkspaceSettings: TEMP autoBuild=false maxFile=-1
File di build: C:\IBM\WCDE_E~1\setup\setup.xml

initialize:
     [echo] Initialization complete
GENERAZIONE COMPLETATA

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
HeadlessWorkspaceSettings: RESTORED autoBuild=false maxFile=-1
HeadlessWorkspaceSettings: INITIAL autoBuild=false maxFile=-1
HeadlessWorkspaceSettings: TEMP autoBuild=false maxFile=-1
File di build: C:\IBM\WCDE_E~1\setup\setup.xml

initialize:
     [echo] Initialization complete
GENERAZIONE COMPLETATA

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
HeadlessWorkspaceSettings: RESTORED autoBuild=false maxFile=-1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no forcing required. If it's enabled in the database but not in EAR you just need to run the enablement again and it will skip the database enablement because it's already done and then enable the feature in ear.

If that doesn't work I suggest disable the feature again and then enable each feature in order. The each feature required by the previous. Example foundation before management-center.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.component-services.doc/tasks/twvenablefoundation.htm?cp=SSZLC2_7.0.0%2F3-7-5-0